# Django tutorial: problems accessing development server

Tags: python, linux, django, centos

I am going through the Django tutorial and am running into problems when trying to view my webpage. I am at the very beginning of the tutorial when I first run the command `python manage.py runserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000` (replace the x's with my remote server's IP). When I try to navigate to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000 on my local machine, Chrome gives me the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I have also tried running the server on `0.0.0.0:8000` and the same issue persists. The port is definitely open and there are no firewalls blocking it - when I plug in my IP and 8000 into this site it claims it is open: http://ping.eu/port-chk/.

I get no error messages on my console from the Django side of things. What could be causing this error? I really don't know much about servers or ports. Thanks in advance.

I am on a virtual Linux server running CentOS 6.4. My local machine is running Mac OS 10.9.5

EDIT:

When I run `netstat --listen`, port 8000 doesn't show up in the Local Address column, even though my Django dev server claims to be running. Someone mentioned to me that this means my application is not listening on this port. What does this mean and how do I remedy it?

EDIT:

I can access the page through my phone's internet with no issues. What gives?

Comment: Which virtualization solution are you using? How is the VM connecting to the host's network (bridging / routing?) What is your Mac's IP address, and what is your VM's IP address?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Django inside a VM but accessing it from the host Mac, you'll need to forward the port. See the settings in Virtualbox/VMWare/whatever.

Note however that Django runs perfectly well directly on a Mac, so if you're just learning it may be simpler to just install it there.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about servers and ports - what do you mean by forward the port? And how would I go about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: And I would love to use it on my Mac, but since I am learning Django for my job, eventually I will have to actually use this server to host my application, so I figured it would be better to learn on it.

Comment: Well it will depend on what virtualization software you're using. On virtualbox, fur example, it's under the Network setting, where there is a button marked Port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Don't issue no IP, `runserver` will tell you where you can connect to when launching it.

Since you're launching it from your VM, you might supply the IP.
Ensure system level routing is okay.

Add your host local IP to the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting.

Comment: If I just use runserver without specifying an IP or port, it will run on 127.0.0.1 which is inaccessible, since my app is on a VM and I am trying to see the app from my local browser.

Comment: Where would I find that setting?

Comment: in the settings.py file. Also set the VM settings to forward ports :)

Comment: I think my problem must be with port forwarding - I have no idea how to do this or what it really means. Where on my centos server would I be able to accomplish this? What am I forwarding to what? Not finding good help by googling.